# Kvpn on ubuntu 11.10 is stuck on 'Connecting'

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I recently installed open-vpn and it's gui, Kvpn, on my ubuntu system but after I load the configuration file and click 'Connect' it just runs through and gets stuck on 'Connecting', never actually getting connected. How do i get around this or what might i be doing wrong?

The profile was set up using a .conf file and the network i'm trying to connect to needs only a username and password. I'm on a wi-fi connection, with one network card(also behind a university firewall, i suppose). Any help regarding connecting to a vpn on ubuntu would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't say what kind of VPN this is (L2TP, PPTP, ...) but one thing that bit me a good while ago was when I had made a mistake typing in the VPN pre-shared key. That was on Windows, admittedly, but it wouldn't get past "connecting", and it took me a while to figure out what the problem was!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to setup firewall forwarding rules for vpn to work correclty.

Comment: Also do i need to setup both a server and a client on my machine before i can connect to a remote vpn??